# Finder bug - wrong drop zone highlight

Tags: macos, finder, bug

Sometimes I experience strange behaviour within the Finder. When I drag files to another Finder window the highlighted drop zones are incorrect and if I attempt to edit a file name the location of the edit-textfield is wrong as well.

[image]

The highlight zone seems to be connected to the Finder windows previous location. I noticed other users had this problem (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6663266?start=0&tstart=0) but no answer was ever supplied.

Has anybody experienced similar issues and found a (preferably permanent) solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Reboot the computer works in a limited time but several days later the bug comes back.

Comment: So - that's an important tidbit. The reboot just cleans up the mess but doesn't prevent whatever bug or thing is causing this from happening again.